# Actualizar Tabla despues de eliminar un registro "datatables"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

estoy usando una tabla https://datatables.net/ con lo cual se muestran mis registros y puedo hacer el crud sin problemas pero hay un detalle al momento de eliminar, que es que cuando elimino un registro muestra una alerta indicando que esta conforme pero el registro aun aparece y se tiene que actualizar la pagina para poder aplicar el cambio, coloque el window.location.reload() que hace que se actualice pero asi se pierde mi alerta de confirmacion, lo que necesitaria saber si hay alguna funcion o proceso para que cuando se elimine un registro solo se actualice la tabla y no la pagina entera.

```
$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function (event) {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let orden = "Eliminar";
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Elimar usuario?',
        text: "Si elimina el usuario no habra forma de recuperalo",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: false,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar',
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCloseButton: true,
        showDenyButton: true,
        denyButtonText: 'cancelar',
        backdrop: `
        rgba(54,70,93,0.95)
        `
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "model/usuarios.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { id: id, action: orden },
                success: function (data) {
                    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                        toast: true,
                        position: 'top-end',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 3000,
                        timerProgressBar: false,
                        showCloseButton: true,

                        didOpen: (toast) => {
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                        }
                    })
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Exito',
                        text: 'asdasd'
                    });
                }
            });
            VistaUsuario();
        }
        else if (result.isDenied) {
            VistaUsuario();
        }
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: lee un poco sobre como remover, https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().delete()   si estas eliminando puedes quitar la fila cuando eliminas y puedes usar fetch de js para ejecutar el eliminar

Comment: sin tu código no es mucho lo que se puede hacer.

Comment: no hay alguna funcion que se ejecute para actualizar la tabla? algo como $('#tabla').reload() o algo asi ? ya que es lo que solo necesitaria que despues de ejecutar el ajax y responda actualice la tabla

Comment: `jQuery` y `javascript` también ofrecen el método `.remove()` con el que puedes eliminar un `<tr>` previamente identificado. Pero, tal como dice @John sin conocer el contexto de tu proyecto no hay mucho que podamos hacer por ti.

Comment: ahi esta el codigo del JS que ejecuta el proceso de eliminar, la alerta se muestra pero después de la alerta necesitaria que se actualice la tabla, o como hacer con el .remove()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
$('#miTabla').on( 'click', '.eliminar', function (event) {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let orden = "Eliminar";
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Elimar usuario?',
        text: "Si elimina el usuario no habra forma de recuperalo",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: false,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar',
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCloseButton: true,
        showDenyButton: true,
        denyButtonText: 'cancelar',
        backdrop: `
        rgba(54,70,93,0.95)
        `
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "model/usuarios.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { id: id, action: orden },
                success: function (data) {

                    miTabla.row( this ).delete();

                    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                        toast: true,
                        position: 'top-end',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 3000,
                        timerProgressBar: false,
                        showCloseButton: true,

                        didOpen: (toast) => {
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                        }
                    })
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Exito',
                        text: 'asdasd'
                    });
                }
            });
            VistaUsuario();
        }
        else if (result.isDenied) {
            VistaUsuario();
        }
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

donde lo que hacemos es cambiar la escucha del evento de:

```
$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function (event) {
```

al elemento previamente definido como dataTable que supuestamente contiene la tabla, que como no aparece en la pregunta, lo he llamado `miTabla`:

```
$('#miTabla').on( 'click', '.eliminar', function (event) {
```

y dentro ya podemos eliminar la fila con el método [delete()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().delete()) de datatables, tal como te han indicado en los comentarios, poniendolo en la sección del `success` para asegurarnos que la eliminación se ha realizado previamente en la llamada ajax al script en PHP:

```
miTabla.row( this ).delete();
```

y dejamos que continue con el resto del código sin ninguna otra variación